# android studio local variable redundant

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Can someone explain to me why it's giving me "local variable is redundant error"?

```
package com.example.smite.floater;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class creator extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.creator ,container,false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

At start it was a different error on the R only
but after I changed the xml this happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your method you are:

- returning a value and after that creating a variable. It is an error, because this code will never run
- you are creating a variable which is not being used

Your code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        // It is after a return statement! 
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.creator ,container,false);
        //You are creating a variable which is not being used
        return v;
    }
```

Use:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,@Nullable ViewGroup container,@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.creator ,container,false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Allocating or creating less objects is a good practice in android. In your case you are allocating a View object which is not being used.

use

```
return inflater.inflate(R.layout.creator ,container,false);
```

instead of

```
View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.creator ,container,false);
        return v;
```